# How do I apply a custom function with multiple data.frames as input in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to use a custom function that takes a row of data from one data.frame (raw_DF) and uses calibration data from a separate data.frame (calibrant_DF) and then calculates the calibrated value of Raw12.  I am getting this error:

> Error in cal_DF$Cal_set : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>   Called from: top level

It seems that the apply function doesn't like having a data.frame passed to it this way so I've spent the past few hours trying to figure out if I can use a different apply function (e.g. mapply, lapply) or a plyr function to accomplish what I'm trying to do but without any luck.  Suggestions?

Example Code (real functions and DF's are more complicated):

```
raw_DF<-data.frame("Cal_set"=c(1,2,1,2),"Raw12"=c(3.3,3.1,5.1,4.2))
calibrant_DF<-data.frame("Cal_set"=c(1,2),"b12"=c(.01,.04),"m12"=c(.95,.99))

apply.cals <- function(raw_row,cal_DF){
  current_cals<-cal_DF[which(cal_DF$Cal_set==raw_row$Cal_set),]
  raw12<-raw_row$Raw12
  cal12<-(raw12-current_cals$b12)/current_cals$m12

  outdata<-data.frame(raw12,cal12)
  return(outdata)
} # End of apply.cals

calibrated_data<-apply(X=raw_DF,MARGIN=1,FUN=apply.cals,cal_DF="calibrant_DF")
```

And my desired output is a data.frame (or something I can put into a data.frame) of results like this:

`raw12    cal12
   3.3 3.463158
   3.1 3.090909
   5.1 5.357895
   4.2 4.20202`

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT - SOLVED, BUT....
I'd be interested in plyr solutions if anyone else has one in mind - that's a function I'd like to understand better and my impression is that this a problem it could deal with elegantly.

Comment: Your function is written as if the argument `cal_DF` is a `data.frame` (presumably; possibly some other 2 dimensional object), but the you are passing `"calibrant_DF"` to it, which is an atomic character vector, not a `data.frame`. If you are trying to pass the object `calibrant_DF` from the global environment, don't quote its name.

Comment: After editing the code to remove those quotes, I receive a different but similar error: `Error in raw_row$Cal_set : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Called from: '[.data.frame'(cal_DF, which(cal_DF$Cal_set == raw_row$Cal_set), 
    )`

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your desired output - I can't say for sure but I suspect that `apply` is the wrong function for whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just added desired results above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` expects a matrix - and if it gets a data frame, it will convert it to a matrix. So you can't rely on `$` with `apply`.

One way to quickly convert your code to something that works is:

```
sapply(split(raw_DF, rownames(raw_DF)), apply.cals, cal_DF=calibrant_DF)
```

`split(raw_df, rownames(raw_DF))` converts raw_DF into a list, where each component is a data frame with just one row. And `sapply` applies your function to each such data frame.

What i get in this example is:

```
#       1        2        3        4      
# raw12 3.3      3.1      5.1      4.2    
# cal12 3.463158 3.090909 5.357895 4.20202
```

(I hope the output makes any sense to you ... )

Comment: Btw .. if you use the above approach I recommend a change in your function a bove - to return a vector instead of a data frame, something like `outdata<-c(raw=raw12,cal=cal12)`. This works better in combination with  `sapply` which likes to put its results into a matrix (data frames forced into a matrix is an ugly data structure).  Alternatively, you can use `lapply` instead of `sapply` and later join the parts with `do.call(rbind, ....)` - then you get a data frame as output. I'm sure `plyr` can do it too, maybe in a shorter way.

Comment: Thanks, your solution should work - I'd like the results in columns but transposing is easy enough.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The solution works well!  I just added a data.frame(t()) wrapper to the output to get it exactly as I wanted.